# Error Xcode build: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_RCTViewManager

Tags: xcode, react-native, apple-m1, xcode14.3

**Hi all.**

- I have a problem when building :
- when I build Xcode for the first time (when cloned from GitHub) I build successfully but when I clean the build folder when I build again the problem occurs as shown in the picture.

**Project information:**

- react-native: 0.64
- Xcode: 14.3

[Log Image Url Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M4OP.png)

I have spent many days researching but still no success. Help me, please.